# Stanford CoreNLP: nndep.DependencyParser in pipeline with geman model

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

i want to use the nndep in CoreNLP for dependency Parsing. So the Input is a simple german sentence and the output should be like this:

```
case(Schulen-3, An-1)
amod(Schulen-3, Stuttgarter-2)
nmod(gegrüßt-13, Schulen-3)
aux(gegrüßt-13, darf-4)
case(MitschülerInnen-7, wegen-5)
amod(MitschülerInnen-7, muslimischer-6)
nmod(gegrüßt-13, MitschülerInnen-7)
neg(gegrüßt-13, nicht-8)
advmod(nicht-8, mehr-9)
case(Gott-12, mit-10)
amod(Gott-12, Grüß-11)
nmod(gegrüßt-13, Gott-12)
root(ROOT-0, gegrüßt-13)
auxpass(gegrüßt-13, werden-14)
punct(gegrüßt-13, .-15)
```

and this command is working for a single file:

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser -model edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_German.gz -textFile /Users/.../input.txt
```

But I need to to this with 60.000 files. So i need the nlp.pipeline. If i execute the following command, the output is only the normal parse tree but not the parsed dependencies.

```
java -Xmx6g -cp "*:." -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP  -filelist /Users/.../filelist.txt -props StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties -outputFormat text -parse.originalDependencies
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

`-annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,depparse`

and

`-pos.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-ud.tagger`

The first addition is telling it to use the dependency parser, the second is telling it to use the UD POS tagger, which is necessary since the dependency parser expects UD POS tags.

Also make sure to use the latest Stanford CoreNLP from GitHub or the last released version (more stable) from here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html